# What is the authentic Mula Mantra of Kala Bhairava?

Tags: scripture, mantras, pramana, bhairava

On the Internet, without any difficulties, you can find many different mantras of Kala Bhairava, but the specific source of origin of these mantras (Tantra, Agama, Grantha, etc.) is always not indicated.
One gets the unpleasant impression that most of them are just someone's fiction.

Comment: Moolamantras or any mantras can't be discussed on online forums. Altough as a hint, a Sapt yojit dwe (Eka yojit Eka) or 7+2 (1+1) form of mantra is used wid seeds, dative form of name & a proper closure to it. Or else Kshterapal mantra too can be used for Kalbhairava.

Comment: But the problem is, what exactly is the text it comes from? In the Tantric traditions of central and northern India, some other mantra may well be used. I need specific texts, where everything comes from.

Comment: The format that I shared is Navakshari mantra. Actually, Im not in the position to write beejas being Adikshit myself. Thus, I avoided that. Apart from this kindly share your any secondary platform Id in the HSE Chatroom, so tht I can share the ss of the same from the shastra.

Answer (score 1):

Together with Chamunda das, we managed to find out the following.

In the Mahakala Samhita, Guhyakali Khanda 2, shloka 1063, the Bhairava mantra of nine syllables (navakshari) is described. Nama-bija (vibhakti samas) should be used in this mantra. Bhairava's name must be in the dative case. In shloka 1064 it is stated that the mantra should be closed with the word "namah" - https://archive.org/details/mahakalasamhitaguhyakalikhandakishornathjhapart2rashitriyasanskritsanstha_202003_632_X/page/n155/mode/2up

Therefore, the given canonical mantra of Kalabhairava is as follows: कां कालभैरवाय नमः

So, my question has been answered. This topic can be closed. Special thanks to Chamunda das.